# Firefox renders page differently depending on wether the style is passed by the style attribute or a .css file

Tags: html, css, firefox, frontend

I think the title sums it up. I have experience with programming but I'm new to web development, perhaps I'm missing something simple. Here is the very short code that I'm having problem with.

```css
.MainPanel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Login {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}

.Register {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1>Login or Register!</h1>

        <div class="Login">
          <div>Login</div>
          <input placeholder="email address" />
          <input placeholder="password" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </div>
        <div class="Register">
          <div>Register</div>
          <input placeholder="email address" />
          <input placeholder="password" />
          <input placeholder="repeat password" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I remove the `style` attribute of the first `div` and add `class="MainPanel"` the result isn't as expected, the content isn't centered.

Answer (score 2):

Every browser has its different default basic style to display a webpage.

To remove any default padding margin from browser in your webpage, write this piece of code at the **beginning** of your stylesheet(css file),

```
   *{ 
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
```

Now add your `class="MainPanel"`

If I've understand your question correctly then this should work!.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer! I've tried this and also reset.css but it doesn't seem to help. I think this problem has to do with something other than the default browser styles.

Comment: Then clean browser cache. And check if css file path is correct.